# Not able to get a result on clicking the items of a list that include radio buttons

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button

I have a list that has a text view and 2 radio buttons in each row.I am using a custom array adapter to populate the list view.I have implemented the on item click listener on the list but it is not returning anything.In fact it not executing the on click method at all.Here is the code:

Adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 Context context; 
 public static ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
 public static ArrayList<String> attendance=new ArrayList<String>();
 RadioGroup radioGroup;
  RadioButton present,absent;
public MyAdapter(Context context,ArrayList values) {
    super(context,org.example.attendance.R.layout.list_radio,values);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


    this.context=context;
    this.values=values;
}

public  View getView(int pos,View convertview,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView=inflator.inflate(org.example.attendance.R.layout.list_radio,parent,false);
        radioGroup=(RadioGroup)rowView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        present=(RadioButton)rowView.findViewById(org.example.attendance.R.id.radio0);
        absent=(RadioButton)rowView.findViewById(org.example.attendance.R.id.radio1);
        TextView textview=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(org.example.attendance.R.id.textView1);
    //  textview.setText(values[pos]);
        //String s=values[pos];

            textview.setText(values.get(pos));
        //int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        //if(selectedId==R.id.radio0)
        return rowView;


    }
 public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() 
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) 
    {
        return true;
    }

 }
```

main class:

```
public class Students_List extends Activity {

Intent i1;
String tablename;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton present,absent;
ArrayList<String> student_name = new ArrayList<String>() ;
public static ArrayList<String> attendance=new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_students__list);
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    i1=getIntent();
    radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    present=(RadioButton)findViewById(org.example.attendance.R.id.radio0);
    absent=(RadioButton)findViewById(org.example.attendance.R.id.radio1);
    tablename=i1.getStringExtra("class")+"_student";
    //Log.d("student","table"+tablename);
    String temp=getServerData(KEY_12);
    listview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,student_name));
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int     position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("view","clicked");
            if(present.isChecked())
            {
            attendance.add("present");
            }
            if(absent.isChecked())
            {
                attendance.add("absent");
            }

}

    });
}
```

list_radio.xml:file that contains the views to populate each row

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

  <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
     <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:paddingRight="45dp"
    android:checked="true" />

  <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </RadioGroup>


  </RelativeLayout>
```

and finally the list view xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/present" 
        android:paddingRight="25dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/absent" />
</LinearLayout>

   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip" 
       android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#f8f8ff"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:textFilterEnabled="true"
        android:textStyle="normal" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/submit" 
    android:onClick="submit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What should i do so that i can get the state of the radio buttons??

Answer (score 0):

Add this element to the layout if your list item:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

and maybe remove it from your main layout?

Answer (score 0):

Here take this code and apply changes to your needs. You need to work by yourself somewhat.

This code is of a spinner list. For more code you can visit
[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-spinner-dropdown-example/).

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: its giving an error that void is not a valid return type for onItemSelected method

Comment: have you downloaded the whole code from the url that I gave? It worked for me. Can you send me the whole code or project for my keen references? If yes then reply I ll give you my email Id